# Best Practice to add UI enhancements to multiple Backbone Marionette views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

So I was what the best way for all views in an application to have actions performed on an element.

In a non single page application you would run say:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.autosize').autosize();
});
```

to apply autosize function to all elements with the autosize class on every page.

Now in a Backbone Marionette app to do this you could perform that in each view with `onDomRefresh` or similar but for things that affect 90% of views you'd want this to run automatically somehow.

I don't think there's a way that an Application object can listen to all `onDomRefresh` events which would potentially solve it. I've consider overloading `Marionette.MonitorDOMRefresh`to add this in but it doesn't feel like a Backbone approach.

Other things I considered were sub-classing each of the marionette views to add mixins for loading different groups of UI elements.

I figured other people must have experienced this scenario so was interested what approaches have been used.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a base View class and inherit from it every view class that needs the autosize enhancement.

```
var AutosizeBaseView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    onDomRefresh: function(){
        this.$('.autosize').autosize();
    }
});
```

then make your classes like this:

```
var SomeView = AutosizeBaseView.extend({
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That doesn't feel right to me though as I'd need to sub class each of the view types for this to cover all views and would need to always call AutosizeBaseView.prototype.onDomRefresh.call(this) from any children that have anything happen on the dom refresh event. Ideally If I'm going to have to subclass all the view types I'd want it to happen without having to worry about calling parent methods

Comment: How many enhancements do you run?? What I do is I put them all on the base class. The $ function is going to take care of run them only for those elements that exist on the DOM and ignore those that don't. You don't need to customize the onDomRefresh on each view.

Comment: we've got about 5 and are early days still in our app. I'd need to call the parent if I hooked anything else up to the onDomRefresh event. Thanks for sharing anyway, good to know I'm not missing something obvious

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't really find any solutions that really solved my problem, despite some helpful chats with @julio_menedez and @marionettejs on Twitter. With a really good idea being using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) but wasn't suitable as I need to support older IE's.

So instead I headed into the dangerous world of monkey patching to solve it (Bear in mind I might need to iron out some wrinkles with this still, just finished writing it and not fully tested it - I'll update accordingly)

In Coffeescript: (javascript version at the bottom)

```
# Monkey patching the Marionette View.. sorry!

# this is the only Marionette view which doesn't have it's own constructor
Marionette.ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend
  constructor: ->
    Marionette.View.prototype.constructor.apply @, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)

original_view_constructor = Marionette.View.prototype.constructor
Marionette.View.EventAggregator = event_aggregator = _.extend {}, Backbone.Events

# all the other constructors call this so we can hijack it
Marionette.View.prototype.constructor = ->
  event_aggregator.listenTo @, 'all', =>
    args_array = Array.prototype.slice.call arguments, 0
    event_aggregator.trigger.apply event_aggregator, [ 'view:' + args_array[0], @ ].concat(args_array.slice(1))
    event_aggregator.stopListening @ if args_array[0] == 'close'
  original_view_constructor.apply @, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
```

And then to use I just setup a listener in my application object to catch view events I need. e.g:

```
@listenTo Marionette.View.EventAggregator, 'view:dom:refresh', (view) ->
  view.$('div').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

So in my view these are the pros and cons of this technique:

Pros:

- Can listen to all view events without injecting all view classes or subclassing all view classes
- Simple to use
- Objects don't need to opt-in to using it at all

Cons

- Uses monkey patching, dangerous to Marionette API Changes
- Uses Marionette namespacing so vulnerable to a future Marionette namespace collision
- Takes dealing with views out of view context
- Having an event aggregator object isn't something seen elsewhere in Backbone/Marionette (afaiw) so breaks a pattern (update - something similar is seen with Backbone.history)

Anyway I'm welcome to feedback, alternatives, criticism :-) and hope maybe this helps someone else in the same situation

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  var event_aggregator, original_view_constructor;

  Marionette.ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    constructor: function() {
      return Marionette.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
    }
  });

  original_view_constructor = Marionette.View.prototype.constructor;

  Marionette.View.EventAggregator = event_aggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

  Marionette.View.prototype.constructor = function() {
    var _this = this;
    event_aggregator.listenTo(this, 'all', function() {
      var args_array;
      args_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
      event_aggregator.trigger.apply(event_aggregator, ['view:' + args_array[0], _this].concat(args_array.slice(1)));
      if (args_array[0] === 'close') {
        return event_aggregator.stopListening(_this);
      }
    });
    return original_view_constructor.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Looks good. Don't think it could be done cleaner, kudos for that!

Answer (score 0):

In CoffeeScript I think you could also do:

```
extend = (obj, mixin) ->
  obj[name] = method for name, method of mixin        
  obj

include = (klass, mixin) ->
  extend klass.prototype, mixin

include Marionette.View,
  onDomRefresh: () -> @$('.autosize').autosize()
```

Which should cover all the view types.  Haven't tested this specifically, but just did something very similar to add functionality to Marionette's Layout view.  Extend / include pattern at http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html.  Of course this should all be doable in straight up JS too.

UPDATE:

Actually, since we have Underscore available to us we don't need to manually define the `include` and `extend` methods.  We can just say:

```
_.extend Marionette.View.prototype,
  onDomRefresh: () -> @$('.autosize').autosize()
```