# DOM afterRender JS manager for Backbone.marionette app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom, marionette

We are currently building a single-page web application using Brian Mann's BackboneRails design patterns (WHICH ARE AWESOME!). This application displays multiple dynamically changing collectionViews. It also uses Pusher (pusher.com) to update these collectionsViews in real-time. We would like to trigger several jQuery DOM-level scripts after each render update (i.e. timeago, dotdotdot, etc) without creating memory leaks through duplication.

We are looking for a design pattern we can use to fire and garbage-collect these scripts.

Attempts to use _.defer or _.delay or strapping the scripts execute to the last possible onRender have been problematic (and left us feeling dirty).

Has anyone created a better scaleable solution for managing the upkeep of jQuery DOM management scripts in a Backbone.Marionette Rails app?

Any advice, even philosophic would be appreciated.

Comment: My challenge seems ver close to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237501/best-practice-to-add-ui-enhancements-to-multiple-backbone-marionette-views) only @kevin-dew seems much deeper into JS than I am. I'm currently exploring extending the Marionette.View.prototype.add function as a re-trigger for JQuery DOM functions. Still a little dirty, but I need to get this done. :-)

Comment: Continuing to diary my own progress... @derick-bailey answers the question [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/20/using-jquery-plugins-and-ui-controls-with-backbone/) sort-of for me. The issue remaining is what happens to memory when I attach jQuery timeAgo to 100 itemViews individually?